# After migrating my web application from SP2010 to SP2013, I get access denied error

Tags: upgrade, access-denied

I successfully migrated my web app from SP2010 to SP2013 without error or warnings

[image]

[image]

But when I tried to access the migrated site, it gives me an Access Denied Error

I already do this from my SP2010 environment (before proceeding to backing up the content database)

```
$WebAppName = "http://<yourWebAppUrl>"
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName
$wa.UseClaimsAuthentication = $true
$wa.Update()

$account = "yourDomain\yourUser"
$account = (New-SPClaimsPrincipal -identity $account -identitytype 1).ToEncodedString()
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName
$zp = $wa.ZonePolicies("Default")
$p = $zp.Add($account,"PSPolicy")
$fc=$wa.PolicyRoles.GetSpecialRole("FullControl")
$p.PolicyRoleBindings.Add($fc)
$wa.Update()

$wa.MigrateUsers($true)

$wa.ProvisionGlobally()
```

I get this error, I am using the administrator account and yet getting an access denied error

[image]

Comment: Can you access the site using the API i.e. Get-SPWeb? If yes try accessing the settings page _layouts/15/settings.aspx

Answer (score 3):

By default when we create a web application in SharePoint 2013, it gets created with Claims authentication. When we migrate the content DB to 2013, it recognizes the user account only in this format i:0#.w|domain\username . Though it’s an AD account it no more recognizes the Domain\UserName format.

SharePoint assumes all users to be claim users and renders them so. Therefore, a normal windows user – “Domain\UserName” appears as “i:0#.w|Domain\UserName”. Moreover, it uses the username in this same format to check for its permissions but does not find a matching entry for the user as the database has windows users – “Domain\UserName”. So, the site will give you an access denied.

Note that the System Account will work since its “Domain\UserName” is never used and System Account is a keyword used by SharePoint for the application pool identity. Therefore, it remains unaffected.

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication -identity "http://serverURL"
$webApp.UseClaimsAuthentication = $true
$webApp.Update()
```

//convert user accounts to claim format

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication -identity "http://serverURL"
$webApp.MigrateUsers($true)
```

then do iisreset

http://www.winwire.com/access-denied-error-after-migrating-to-sharepoint-2013/

Since you have done everything as mention above,you might want to check if the site is using claim authentication using the following script:

```
$web = Get-SPWebApplication "<URL for Application>" 
$web.UseClaimsAuthentication
```

If return false then you might need to re-run the script as shown above

If still not working try the following:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://webappurl
$webApp.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"] = "<claimsId>
$webApp.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"] = <claimsId>
$webapp.Update()
```

If still not working, then it worth to configure object cache at Web application level:

**Configure object cache settings**

- Verify that you have the following administrative credentials: You must be a member of the Administrators group on the local computer to configure the object cache settings.
- Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
- In Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, in the Connections pane, click the plus sign (+) next to the server name that contains the web application, and then click the plus sign next to Sites to view the web application or applications that have been created.
- Right-click the name of the web application for which you want to configure the disk-based cache, and then click Explore. Windows Explorer opens, with the directories for the selected web application listed.
- Right-click web.config, and then click Open.
- If the Windows dialog box appears, select Select a program from a list of installed programs, and then click OK.
- In the Open With dialog box, click Notepad, and then click OK.
- In the Web.config Notepad file, find the following line:
- To change the size of the cache, type a new number for maxSize. The size is expressed in megabytes (MB), and 100 MB is the default.
- Save the Notepad file, and then close it.

link:https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770229(v=office.15).aspx#object

Comment: I can now access the site using this code in powershell: $WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication “http://WebAppURL” Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity $WebApp -To Claims –RetainPermissions -Verbose $WebApp.MigrateUsers($true) But when I try to access the site settings, it will give me again the "Access Denied Error"

Comment: Done your suggestion above, but still getting the "Access Denied" error when I am trying to go to site settings

Comment: Hi Ruel, I have update the post. Could you try the last script.Let me how it goes.thx

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: Try to configure object cache setting. Please refer to my update post above

Comment: Going to throw this in hoping search engines pick it up.  I had to manually configure super user and super reader only *after* the visual upgrade.  Was getting "this site hasn't been shared with you" after I did the SP2013 visual upgrade but not before.  Setting the super user and super reader fixed that